# How to change the style of an HTML field based on the change of an object in java?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I have a jsp page in which I display the records in a database table. There is a status field in each record which displays ok or not ok. I have a requirement that I need to change the header background of the HTML table based on the following rules

1. If all the records have status ok then the header background will be green.
2. If all records have status not ok then the header background will be dark red.
3. If some records have status not ok then the header background will be yellow.

How do I implement this?

Comment: Also, it's better to write logic in java and set request attribute which would indicate the final status, instead of putting this whole logic in JSP

Comment: Please post the code you tried. We can help you where you are wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Style should be altered by changing the CSS class appropriately, based on the status value.

How you do that depends on how you generate your HTML.

If you use a server side, using a dynamic template solution like Velocity or Thymeleaf, you should change the class name using if/else logic in templates.

If you want a client side solution, then jquery is best for DOM manipulation.

Comment: So I should do something like below?



`<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${condition_all_ok}">
        <c:set var="headerclass" value="greenBkgrndClass"/>
    </c:when>
     <c:when test="${condition_all_not_ok}">
        <c:set var="headerclass" value="redBkgrndClass"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="headerclass" value="yellowBkgrndClass"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
<td class="${headerclass}">`

Answer (score 0):

Possible other solution : I have come with in past. I am not sure if it is the right way to do .

1. Now you are fetching the rows from database into the jsp page in a table. 
   Just while you fetch check whether if all records status are

   1. All OK
   2. All not OK
   3. Some Ok

   And set a variable say `int status to 1,2 or 3` respectively.
2. Make a hidden div after the table and give the status value to it.

   `<div id="hiddenx" hidden> <%=status%> </div>`
3. Now using Javascript

   ```
   window.onload = function() {
     var x = document.getElementById("hiddenx").value;
     if(x == 1){
     document.getElementById("header").style.color = "green";
     }else if(x == 2){
     document.getElementById("header").style.color = "darkred"; // set the colrrect one
    }else{
     document.getElementById("header").style.color = "yellow";
   }
   };
   ```

Comment: < div hidden id="hiddenx"> <%=status%>  </div> 

Please help, I have no idea why this code is not getting showed properly

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set the status in java code with different viriable,then you can get them in jsp page and achieve your purpose.